# Autoamte SPSS from Access with VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, spss

I have an Access database (2010) which needs to automatically send data to SPSS, have statistical functions run on it there, and then export said information back into Access. I need to know wheter it is possible to do these workflow steps all from Access using VBA.

I have found some instructional material on the IBM Website which indicates that you can hook up an Access Database to SPSS using ODBC drivers. I have also found information on automating SPSS using their scripting language.

Saddly I have not found any information on the web of anyone having used VBA to automate SPSS. What I would like to know is: a) **can it be done?** and b) **would I need to learn the SPSS scripting language to do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPSS Statistics has a full set of automation methods available similar to VBA in Office.  Look at the help for Basic scripting in Statistics or reference the SPSS automation libraries from Access.  These methods are not limited to use from Basic, but if you are starting with Access VBA, that would be a reasonable way to do this.